# Is there any guideline or procedure for 4G hardware equipement (4G landline phone and home Wifi router) security audit/assessment?

Tags: penetration-test, hardware, hardening, vulnerability-assessment

I need to perform a security audit/assessment on 4G LTE hardware equimements :

- 4G landline wireless phone (not android OS but with many features such as WiFi hotspot)
- 4G Wifi home router

Is there any standard/guideline/procedure (or any checklist on the subject) that exists that I could use to perform a security assessment/audit ?

I was not given an system image (I would have binwalk it lol)

Comment: There is a mobile device Protection Profile that may have some relevance https://www.commoncriteriaportal.org/files/ppfiles/pp_md_v3.1.pdf, but clearly not all is applicable. And it's Common Criteria... Other Protection Profiles may have some relevance https://www.commoncriteriaportal.org/pps/. In any case a lot of underlying technologies will have best practices that would be worth checking. E.g. if there is a web management interface standard AppSec practices should be followed, and also TLS best practices etc...